# How can I get the new Xcode console output?

Tags: xcode, logging, console, output

I came across an article showing how to use the new Xcode console together with logging to have a structured and clear output.

This is the article: https://medium.com/@alessandromanilii/custom-swift-logger-in-xcode15-19da40a058a5

This is how I want it to look:
[image]
Note that the separator lines in the screenshot above are added by Xcode. This is what I mostly want from this screenshot

This is how it looks now:
[image]

I cannot for the love of God find how to modify my current console setup to look neat and grouped like in the medium article.

I tried changing the theme to the default one and looked in all the Xcode settings but I guess I'm missing something.